# how to generate swagger 2.0 documentation for FastAPI

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi

I am using FastAPI to develop a microservice and deploy it to Cloud Run. I am adding API Gateway in front of API Gateway. While creating API Gateway, it is asking me to upload API Spec file. Because I am using FastAPI, the documentation that is being generated is for 3.0.2.

I tried to override `custom_openapi` definition and provide `openapi_version` but it does not work and I am getting an error saying

> Unable to render this definition The provided definition does not
> specify a valid version field.
>
> Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported
> version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.0.n
> (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).

This is how my `custom_openapi` definition looks like:

```
def custom_openapi():
    if app.openapi_schema:
        return app.openapi_schema
    openapi_schema = get_openapi(
        title="Custom title",
        version="2.5.0",
        description="This is a very custom OpenAPI schema",
        routes=app.routes,
        openapi_version="swagger:2.0" # I have tried 2.0

    )
```

Is there a way I can generate Swagger 2.0 documentation for my FastAPI?

Comment: It seems like 2.0 is not supported in FastAPI - only 3.0: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/70

Comment: BTW, what advantage do you get by serving your docs from API Gateway instead of from FastAPI?

Comment: @ronrothman I think he is not serving docs from API Gateway. The gateway doesn't support OpenAPI v.3 and requires version 2. This is it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FastAPI to generate OpenAPI 3.0.

And use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/api-spec-converter to convert it to Swagger 2.0

Warning : it works with fastapi==0.98.0
It is not working since fastapi 0.99 as it switched to OpenAPI 3.1 (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/release-notes/#0990)

You need to add this code to your app :

```
@app.get("/openapi_v2")
async def openapi_v2():
    schema = app.openapi()
    schema.update(
        host="your.app.com",
        schemes=["https"],
        produces=["application/json"],
    )

    if len(schema["paths"]) == 0:
        return schema

    endpoint = list(schema["paths"].keys())[0]
    schema["paths"]["/"] = schema["paths"][endpoint]
    del schema["paths"][endpoint]

    for endpoint in schema["paths"].keys():
        for method in schema["paths"][endpoint].keys():
            if "tags" in schema["paths"][endpoint][method]:
                del schema["paths"][endpoint][method]["tags"]

            schema["paths"][endpoint][method]["x-google-backend"] = {
                "address": "https://your.app.com",
                "path_translation": "APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS",
                "protocol": "h2",
            }

    return schema
```

then this should do the job :

```
api-spec-converter --from=openapi_3 --to=swagger_2 http://localhost:5000/openapi_v2
```